# Plated hole without circles on layers

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, through-hole

I am a beginner on Eagle. I want make a plated hole on PCB but no any pad on top or bottom layers. Or, a plated hole on PCB but bottom and top layers are electrically isolated. Another
variation is plated hole with a circle only on bottom or top layer.
In all cases plated hole connected with isolated copper wire (trace).
How can I do this with Eagle?

Comment: i do small research on google, what i need is called "tented plated hole" or "solder mask aplied plated hole"

Comment: Do you think tenting is good enough to guarantee "electrical isolation"?

Comment: im not really sure

Comment: I can't tell -- are you talking about a "via" (layer-to-layer electrical connection) or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a via to a track and set via pad size to whatever you wish.
There will be a minimum size to obtain reliability.
Your PCB supplier will (or should) have design rules covering this.

Comment: this isn't possible with eagle? http://www.eurocircuits.com/images/easyblog_images/68/Via-gold/1_via%20%20half%20open.png